# comparing queue sizes in a vector

Tags: c++, loops, vector, queue

**UPDATED**

Having a logic that where a integer before gets enqueued to a queue in a vector, the loop of queues is searched and integer is enqueued to a queue which has minimum size among the queues. The following code shows the operation

```
#include <vector> 
#include <queue> 
std::vector<std::queue<int> > q
int min_index = 0;
std::size_t size = q.size();
for( i=0; i<size; i++){ //accessing loop of queues
    if(q[min_index].size() > q[i].size())
        min_index = i; // Now q[min_index] is the shortest queue
} 
q[min_index].push(int)
```

i am trying extend this logic with a condition that the integers should get continued to enqueue in the shortest queue **while the condition is true** that the shortest queue's size is less than or equal to any another queue's size in the loop of queues.

i want to do something like the code shown below

```
#include <vector> 
    #include <queue> 
    std::vector<std::queue<int> > q
    int min_index = 0;
    std::size_t size = q.size();
    for( i=0; i<size; i++){ //accessing loop of queues
        if(q[min_index].size() > q[i].size())
            min_index = i

    while(q[min_index].size <= q[some_other_index].size() )
    {
        q[min_index].push(int);

}
```

how to implement this logic?

Comment: Just do a check for shortest queue again inside the `while` loop?

Comment: @joachim pileborgInside while loop the shortest queue size will be compared to the all other queue sizes present in the vector. If the shortest queue size is less than or equal to any another queue size in the loop of queues, it will push the integers. else it will come out of the loop

Comment: @billa By definition, the shortest queue size will be less than or equal to any other queue size.  Otherwise, it's not the shortest.

Comment: @JamesKanzeYes exactly, i was trying to say 'while shortest queue size is less than or equal to any another queue size in the loop of queues, it will push the integers'

Comment: @billa you should update the question. Right now it says "until" but you just said "while". Also: Can you sort the vector of queues? What happens when you fill the shortest queue - is it done or do you pick another queue and start anew? Is this happening inside a function and if it is, how do you call the function? Where are the elements to push coming from? Etc... There's a lot of info you can share that'll help people answering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest solution requires C++11:

```
std::min_element( 
        q.begin(),
        q.end(),
        []( std::queue<int> const& lhs, std::queue<int> const& rhs)
            { return lhs.size() < rhs.size(); } )
    ->push(value);
```

Even without C++11, I think I'd write a small predicate class to
do what the lambda does, and use this.

### EDIT:

Now that I have a better idea as to what is wanted, something
like the following should do the trick:

```
class OrderInMap
{
    MultiQueue* myOwner;
public:
    OrderInMap( MultiQueue* owner )
        : myOwner( owner )
    {
    }
    bool operator()( int lhs, int rhs ) const
    {
        return myOwner->myQueues[ lhs ].size()
                < myOwner->myQueues[ rhs ].size();
    }
};

std::vector <std::queue<int>> myQueues;
std::vector <int> myMap;
int myCurrent;
bool myOrderIsValid;
OrderInMap myOrder;

int getIndexForPush()
{
    if ( ! myOrderIsValid || myOrder( myMap[0], myCurrent ) ) {
        myMap.push_back( myCurrent );
        std::push_heap( myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), myOrder );
        std::pop_heap( myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), myOrder );
        myCurrent = myMap.back();
        myMap.pop_back();
    }
    return myCurrent;
}
```

Since popping can change the order, you'll have to set
`myOrderIsValid` to false when you pop (or perhaps only if after
the pop, `myOrder( poppedIndex, myMap.front() )`).

Alternatively, you can do it by hand, and avoid the map (but you
do have to keep two variables):

```
int myCurrent;
int myNext;

void order()
{
    if ( myQueues[myNext].size() < myQueues[myCurrent].size() ) {
        std::swap( myNext, myCurrent );
    }
}
int getQueueIndex()
{
    if ( ! myOrderIsValid || myQueues[myNext].size() < myQueues[myCurrent].size() ) {
        myCurrent = 0;
        myNext = 1;
        order();
        for ( int i = 2; i < myQueues.size(); ++ i ) {
            if ( myQueues[i].size() < myQueues[myNext].size() ) {
                myNext = i;
                order();
            }
        }
    }
    return myCurrent;
}
```

This is probably slower than maintaining the heap, but even with
a very large number of queues, I'm not sure the difference will
be noticeable.

Comment: You've algorithm-ified / fixed the first code snippet. I think what the questioner *wants* is some kind of optimization to avoid scanning the whole of `q` for each `push` operation -- that is to say the quantity "any other queue size" in the comment in the second code snippet should be cached. I may be wrong

Comment: @SteveJessop Maybe.  He keeps saying something about the shortest queue size being less than or equal to the other sizes, which doesn't tell me anything.  If the goal is to avoid having to do the search each time, one solution would be to use an `std::vector<int>` to map the indexes, and use `std::partial_sort` anytime the second entry was smaller than the first.  But a manual loop looking for the two smallest in parallel might be quicker (and shouldn't be too hard to implement).

Comment: @JamesKanzeI have updated the question, i am very sorry that i was wrong with the until, instead of while

Comment: @JamesKanzeI think we should find two successive minimum and compare it? shall i post it as new question?

Comment: @billa If that's the case, you might try maintaining a map, using either `std::partial_sort` or the heap management functions.

Comment: @billa Just to let you know, I've edited my answer to show some code for the above.