# finding successive minimum and compare in a vector of queues

Tags: c++, sorting, loops, vector, queue

i just implement a logic where a integer before gets enqueued to a queue, the loop of queues in a vector is searched and integer is enqueued to a queue which has minimum size among the queues. the following code shows the operation.

```
#include <vector> 
#include <queue> 
std::vector<std::queue<int> > q
int min_index = 0;
std::size_t size = q.size();
for( i=0; i<size; i++){ //accessing loop of queues
    if(q[min_index].size() > q[i].size())
        min_index = i; // Now q[min_index] is the shortest queue
} 
q[min_index].push(int)
```

now additionally i would like to extend my paradigm with a condition that the integers should get continued to enqueue in the shortest queue **while the condition is true** that the shortest queue's size is less than or equal to any another queue's size in the loop of queues.

want to do something like the code shown below

```
#include <vector> 
    #include <queue> 
    std::vector<std::queue<int> > q
    int min_index = 0;
    std::size_t size = q.size();
    for( i=0; i<size; i++){ //accessing loop of queues
        if(q[min_index].size() > q[i].size())
            min_index = i

    while(q[min_index].size <= q[some_other_index].size() )
    {
        q[min_index].push(int);

}
```

i think i should find successive minimas of the loop and compare it in the while loop? but i don't know how to proceed to mind find successive minimas.

continuation of this question as i didn't ask the question clearly
[comparing queue sizes in a vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894658/comparing-queue-sizes-in-a-vector)

Comment: are you able to mutate the `q` at all?

Comment: It sounds like you need a class to wrap this vector of queue's so that it can maintain the property you want.

Comment: this statement while(q[min_index].size <= q[some_other_index].size() )wont work really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the other queues aren't changed while your loop is ongoing, you can use the initial minimum-search to find the **two** shortest queues. Something like:

```
std::size_t min_index = 0;
std::size_t second_shortest_index = 0;
std::size_t size = q.size();
for( i=0; i<size; i++){ //accessing loop of queues
    if(q[min_index].size() > q[i].size()) {
        second_shortest_index = min_index; 
        min_index = i; // Now q[min_index] is the shortest queue
    } else if (q[second_shortest_index].size() > q[i].size()) {
        second_shortest_index = min_index;
    }
}
```

You can then use `second_shortest_index` as your `some_other_index`. This will still require you to search a new second-shortest queue, when you hit that limit (as there may be multiple shortest or second-shortest elements)

If you can reorder your `vector<queue>` or using an index vector with an indirect comparator, you could use `std::make_heap` and related functions to keep track of smallest queue much more easily.

Comment: @joergB'This will still require you to search a new second-shortest queue, when you hit that limit' so this means that everytime the while loop is false, will search again for the shortest and 2nd shortest queue.?

Comment: @billa: yes, if you want to continue inserting into the smallest queue after the while loop stops. BTW: once you have hit this, each while loop will just have one iteration. To do better, you could you keep something like a priority queue of queue indices. (That is what my `make_heap` suggestion amounts to.)

Comment: @joergBIn the code shown above, overall the integers will get enqueued to the shortest queue until its count its equal to the 2nd shortest queue, right?

Comment: If my code is followed by your while loop (with `some_other_index` replaced by `second_shortest_index`): almost. They will get enqueued to the shortest queue until its count is larger (by `1`) than the count of what used to be the second shortest. Note that right from the start, the "second-shortest" may have had the same length as the shortest; in that case the code will still insert one item to one of the shortest queues.

Comment: @joergByes i understood what you meant, shortest queue will have a enqueue until its count is larger (by 1) than the 2nd shortest queue. thanks for the interaction.:)

Comment: @jeorgBOne small doubt, if i want to add a numerical value to a particular queuesize in the loop of queues of the above code. will this one `q[i].size=q[i].size+5` increase the the queuesize 5 more of the ith queue in loop of queues